# Nash in demand functions!

Tags: mathematical-economics, game-theory, supply-and-demand, finance, nash-equilibrium

I am searching for some types of games that are played in linear demand functions. Altough I hear that there is a vast literatrure for games that are played in the intercept or the slope of the demand functions, there are no games palyed in both the intercept andthe slope, although I do not understand if the latter for a double game has any logic. I am intresting in some type of this game [of Marzena Rostek and Marek Weretka](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/baaa/a13d221472f04870be6822d1b7d4719548c0.pdf), especially the static one. I am searching for any help in the maths that they use, where I can not understand them so much since they make very strange the notation. Does anybody know where to look for? They claim that they paly a Nash game in demand functions and they use some kind of stochastic intercept argument!